# Why new StringBuffer(new StringBuilder("foo")) does work?

Tags: java, scjp

I'm studying for the SCJP certificate and while playing with the StringBuilder and StringBuffer API's I found some situations I can't understand what is happening there.

Here is my example code:

```
    StringBuffer sb1 = new StringBuffer("sb1");
    StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder("sb2");

    StringBuffer sb11 = new StringBuffer(sb1);
    StringBuilder sb22 = new StringBuilder(sb2);

    StringBuffer sb12 = new StringBuffer(sb2);
    StringBuilder sb21 = new StringBuilder(sb1);

    System.out.println(sb1);
    System.out.println(sb2);
    System.out.println(sb11);
    System.out.println(sb22);
    System.out.println(sb12);
    System.out.println(sb21);

    System.out.println();
    sb1.append("a1");
    sb2.append("a2");

    System.out.println(sb1);
    System.out.println(sb2);
    System.out.println(sb11);
    System.out.println(sb22);
    System.out.println(sb12);
    System.out.println(sb21);
```

And here is the result of running the code above:

```
sb1
sb2
sb1
sb2
sb2
sb1

sb1a1
sb2a2
sb1
sb2
sb2
sb1
```

The constructors used for sb11, sb22, sb12 and sb21 are not documented in the API. Furthermore, looking at the results it seems like for those 4 cases the constructor that admits a String or CharSequence is the one used.

If it is true, why is Java automatically converting a StringBuffer in a String? As far as I know Autoboxing does not go that far.

What am I missing?

Comment: If you want to see which constructor or method you are using in your IDE you can use `<ctrl>`+`<click>` on the constructor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both `StringBuilder` and `StringBuffer` implement the `CharSequence` interface, and both have a constructor that takes a `CharSequence` parameter.

Answer (score 3):

`StringBuilder` and `StringBuffer` both implement `CharSequence`.

Answer (score 0):

both of them implement CharSequence. the only difference between them is StringBuffer methods are synchronized whereas stringBuilder is not